# Angular Rxjs get errors from observables array via forkJoin after execution

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I built an array of observables via a forloop. I then use forkjoin to execute them in order and refresh the view after they all complete via .add().

```
    let observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
    this.selection.selected.forEach((person) => {
      // API CALL.
      observables.push(this._personService.deletePerson(person.ID));
    });

    forkJoin(observables)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(dataArray => {})
      .add(() => {
        this._snackbars.openSnackbarShowResults("Mass Delete Completed.");
        this.refresh();
    });
```

I need a way to keep track of which observables failed and returned an error. I use these errors to inform the user which objects could not be deleted and which ones could. Is there an easy way to get which observables had an error after the forkJoin is completed?

Essentially a list of **failed** and **completed** observables from the forkJoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a catch block on the observable that you are pushing in an array. This way you can decide what the output has to be when it fails. Try the below code snippet and verify your console log:

```
let observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
this.selection.selected.forEach((person) => {
  // API CALL.
  observables.push(this._personService.deletePerson(person.ID).catch(() => Observable.of(false)));
});

forkJoin(observables)
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(dataArray => { console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray)); })
  .add(() => {
    this._snackbars.openSnackbarShowResults("Mass Delete Completed.");
    this.refresh();
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Are the Observables always logged in the order that they were added into the array?

Comment: Yes, they are. The order remains intact

Answer (score 1):

A better approach using `rxjs` would be to pipe a `catchError` operator which would store the error message in an object which you can use later. Once you have handled the error, you may pass an observable of null

```
.pipe(
    catchError(err => {
        this.errors["errorForObservable1"] = "error";
        return of(null);
    })
)
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-handle-errors